# Get the name of a month in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am new to application insights and I am writing a query to pull few data from Azure. I need to fetch the name of the month. I tried the below query, but I am getting just the numeric value of 1 in output. 
I need the value as string in a separate column like "January", "February". *Below is the output snap:*

[image: Output]

*Query I wrote:*

`customEvents | summarize Count = dcount(cloud_RoleInstance) by ProductVersion = tostring(customDimensions.["Version"]), Month = monthofyear(timestamp)`

Any suggestion would be highly helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in function for this. So you should define a [user-defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions) to achieve this.

The sample code like below, and you can modify it to meet your need:

```
let f=(a:int){
case(a==1,"Jan",
     a==2,"Feb",
     a==3,"Mar",
     //add the other month
     a==12,"Dec",
     "Error"
)
};
traces 
| summarize count() by cloud_RoleName ,Month=f(getmonth(timestamp))
```

The test result:

[image]

And here is the query just for your case, please add other month in the function.

```
let f=(a:int){
case(a==1,"Jan",
     a==2,"Feb",
     a==3,"Mar",
     //add the other month
     a==12,"Dec",
     "Error"
)
};
customEvents 
| summarize Count = dcount(cloud_RoleInstance) by ProductVersion = tostring(customDimensions.["Version"]), Month = f(getmonth(timestamp))
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is a time saver and works as expected:-)